# Can I submitting my iOS app by nickname?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

If I have a personal developer account in Apple Developer , can I submitting my app by nickname not my real name?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the **Copyright** you can do it easily by yourself.

Otherwise the easiest way to change your seller name is to:

> Contact Apple developer support. If there is a typo or inaccuracy in
>   your seller name they should be willing to change it. Back before I
>   released Card Share my individual account had a seller name for a
>   fictitious entity that did not exist. Since it wasn’t my legal name,
>   Apple support was willing to make the name change. I contacted support
>   and within 24 hours my seller name was changed and updated in the App
>   Store. The results from this method may vary, but I highly recommend
>   direct communication with Apple as a first approach.

Checkout [this](http://www.brynbodayle.com/changing-app-store-seller-name/) reference page.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

[Choose whichever name you want.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2015064?tstart=0)